# display text if in mysql there is a number

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a database with 4 columns, `id`, `user`, `vipplan` and `expire`.
What i want to do, is this:

i have my `vipplan` table, and:
if number 0 is in database: then display "N/A"
if number 1 is in database: then display "Sr.Pro"
if number 2 is in database: then display "No seas"
if number 3 is in database: then display "Level0"

But i do not know how to do it, i post my code:

```
<?php
echo "<h2>Resultados:</h2><p>";

  if(isset($_POST['user']))
        {
        $find = $_POST['user'];
        if ($find == "")
        {
        echo "<p>Olvidaste poner tu usuario -.-!!!";
        exit;
        }
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "2513") or             die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("invasionvip") or die(mysql_error());
            $find = strtoupper($find);
            $find = strip_tags($find);
            $find = trim ($find);
            $iname = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE usuario LIKE '%$find%'")
             or die(mysql_error());
            while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $iname ))
            {
            echo "id:" .$result['id'];
            echo "<br>";
            echo "usuario:".$result['usuario'];
            echo "<br>";
            echo "Plan VIP:".$result['planvip'];
            echo "<br>";
            echo "Vencimiento :".$result['vencimiento'];
            echo "<br>";
            }
            $anymatches = mysql_num_rows($iname);
            if ($anymatches == 0)
            {
            echo "Sorry, but we can not find an entry to match your query...<br><br>";
            }
            echo "<b>Searched For:</b> " .$find;
            }
            ?>
```

and my form is very simple:

```
<form class="pure-form" method="post" action="user.php">
<center>Aqui podrás ver tus servicios activos, como V.I.P, vehiculos, skins, etc.</center><br/>
<span style="text-align:left;font-size:25px;">Usuario:&nbsp;</span>
<input type="text" name="user">
<button type="submit" class="pure-button">Search</button>
</form>
```

thank you, :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are after is a [case select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082894/switch-with-like-inside-select-query-in-mysql). You should put this in the select line of your query.

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple way that you can achieve this ourput
i thing the easiest way is `switch` statement second `if else if and else` third one is array notation which **@b0s3** define earlier.

**Switch example**

```
switch(expression) {
    case 1:
        echo "Sr.Pro";
        break;
    case 2:
        echo "No seas";
        break;
    case 3:
        echo "Level0";
        break;
    default:
        echo "N/A";
}
```

**if else example**

```
if( $databaseValue == 1 ){
    echo "Sr.Pro";
}else if( $databaseValue == 2 ){
    echo "No seas";
}else if( $databaseValue == 3 ){
    echo "Level0";
}else{
    echo "N/A";
}
```

**Array Example**

```
$yourValues = ['N/A', 'Sr.Pro', 'No seas', 'Level0'];

echo $yourValues[$databaseValue];
```

now it's up to your which one you like to use

Comment: what data you store in $planvip column?? you said in this column would be  number 0, 1, 2, 3

Comment: it is, i store numbers, 0, 1, 2 and 3

Comment: then it must return desire value

Comment: put your some effort in order to determine what error actually is

Comment: i am still having problems, i´ve been trying for 2 hours now, and i keep having mistakes, do you have any idea what it can be?

Comment: Hello, i am still trying to determine what the error is, and i have no success, i have something that says ( ! ) Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\www\InvasionVIP\user.php on line 55

Comment: i think the problem is how to insert the array into the while, i have been trying for so long now, and i cant think of a way to make it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ["case"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) expression in the mysql select line.

This is a switch statement that allows you to return an arbitrary value for different conditions.

```
SELECT 
  CASE number 
    WHEN 0 THEN "N/A" 
    WHEN 1 THEN "Sr.Pro" 
    WHEN 2 THEN "No seas" 
    WHEN 3 THEN "Level0" 
  END CASE
FROM table_exemple
```